# What is the difference between a program compiled with -g and -O0

Tags: gcc, optimization

I was thinking the other day and this came to mind. I heard that -g turn off optimizations for debugging, but -O0 does turn off all optimizations, right? I am just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard that -g turn off optimizations for debugging

That's not true.  `-g` only tells the compiler to include debug information in the object file; it has no effect on the code that is actually generated, and it can be used in combination with any optimization option you like.  It will be more *useful* when used with `-O0` or `-Og`, as higher optimization levels can change the code in ways that makes it hard to use a debugger, but this is not mandatory.

> but -O0 does turn off all optimizations, right?

Yes, that is correct; at least, all optimizations that can be turned off at all.  (As JcWasmx86 points out, there are some "optimizations" that are done even at `-O0`, but you can expect them to be transformations that won't require significant compile time or dramatically change the structure of the generated code.)

Comment: Actually not all. In GIMPLE, there are some optimizations, that can't be disabled. (Like transforming 1+2 to 3)

Comment: I guess maybe there's a fuzzy line between "optimization" and "inherent behavior of the compiler".  Dead code elimination seems to be another example.